# How do I debug json file using binding.pry in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I am writing spec for controller and want to debug json file using `binding.pry` command.

How can I see its content If I'm parsing json like the following:

```
 it { expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).[0]).to have_key('id')}
```

Comment: @Albin I tried `JSON`, `JSON.body`, `JSON.parse(response.body)` outside of `it` block and none of these commands works.

Comment: How does the error messages look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either more the parsing outside the expectation, or add another temporary parse statement.

```
it do 
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  binding.pry # start a REPL session
  expect(body).[0]).to have_key('id')
end
```

Also note your code has a syntax error. I don't understand what `.[0]` is supposed to do. The `.to` call should follow the `expect()` statement whereas in your case it's not. Assuming you want to access the first item of the body Array you should write

```
it { expect(JSON.parse(response.body).first).to have_key('id')}
```

or

```
it { expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[0]).to have_key('id')}
```